# Convert a string unicode number into represented unicode character

Tags: python, unicode

I wrote a function that returns a generated unicode nr string:

```
    def __str__(self):
     return '0001F0' + chr(ord('A')+self.color.value-1) + \
        hex(self.value.value).lstrip('0x').rstrip('L')
```

Result:

```
print(Card(Color(1), Value(2))) #'0001F0A2'
```

But I can't figure out how to print out the unicode char it represents, ie. the result you would get with:

```
print('\U0001F0A2')
```

Trying to just add the prefix '\U' like this:

```
    def __str__(self):
    return '\U' + '0001F0' + chr(ord('A')+self.suit.value-1) + \
        hex(self.rank.value).lstrip('0x').rstrip('L')
```

Throws an error:

```
    return '\U' + '0001F0' + chr(ord('A')+self.suit.value-1) + \
                ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

I haven't been able to find the solution online and the things I tried haven't worked.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code that throws the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this will help:

```
def f(x):
    return chr(int(x, 16))
f('1F0A2')
```

output:

```
'' #'PLAYING CARD TWO OF SPADES'
```

Comment: You can compose a `hex` number as a string, using '0x'+... convert it to `int` and return a unicode char, using `chr`. (leading '0' in '0x...' notation are unnecessary)

Comment: I don't quite understand all of your code (probably because it's not all present in the example you showed), and it seems to me that there must be a better way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: You don't need the `0x'` prefix to parse an integer with base 16. Cf. `int('1F0A2', 16) == int('0x1F0A2', 16)`

Comment: Indeed, you don't